# Spring - Testing method that use TransactionSynchronizationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I use in my service `TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(...)` and I cannot write test for this method, because I get an exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction synchronization is not active`.

Implementation of my service:

```
@Transactional
public void save(Order order) {
    log.info("Starting transaction...");
    orderDAO.save(order);
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
            new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void afterCommit() {
                    log.info("#afterCommit");
                    eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OrderPlacedEvent(order));
                }
            }
    );
    log.info("Commit");
}
```

And test which doesn't work:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class OrderServiceTest {

    private OrderDAO orderDAO;
    private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        orderDAO = mock(OrderDAO.class);
        eventPublisher = mock(ApplicationEventPublisher.class);
        orderService = new OrderService(
                orderDAO,
                eventPublisher
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void save() throws Exception {
        // given
        final Order order = new Order(1L, "ORDER");

        // when
        orderService.save(order);

        // then
        verify(orderDAO).save(any(Order.class));
        verify(eventPublisher).publishEvent(any(OrderPlacedEvent.class));
    }

}
```

And stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction synchronization is not active

    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:291)
    at com.events.eventsdemo.services.OrderService.save(OrderService.java:32)
    at com.events.eventsdemo.services.OrderServiceTest.save(OrderServiceTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

UPDATE:

Implementation of my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionsDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TransactionsDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class OrderService {

    private final OrderDAO orderDAO;
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    @Autowired
    public OrderService(OrderDAO orderDAO, ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher) {
        this.orderDAO = orderDAO;
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(Order order) {
        log.info("Starting transaction...");
        orderDAO.save(order);
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
                new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void afterCommit() {
                        log.info("#afterCommit");
                        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OrderPlacedEvent(order));
                    }
                }
        );
        log.info("Commit");
    }
}
```

and test for Service:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class OrderServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private OrderDAO orderDAO;

    @MockBean
    private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Test
    public void save() throws Exception {
        // given
        final Order order = new Order(1L, "ORDER");

        // when
        orderService.save(order);

        // then
        verify(orderDAO).save(any(Order.class));
        verify(eventPublisher).publishEvent(any(OrderPlacedEvent.class));
    }

}
```

but I get an exception:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher#0 bean.publishEvent(
    <any>
);
-> at com.transactions.demo.transactionsdemo.dao.OrderServiceTest.save(OrderServiceTest.java:39)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher#0 bean.publishEvent(
    <any>
);
-> at com.transactions.demo.transactionsdemo.dao.OrderServiceTest.save(OrderServiceTest.java:39)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.transactions.demo.transactionsdemo.dao.OrderServiceTest.save(OrderServiceTest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Maybe I should mock `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter`? But I don't know how to inject mocked implementation of this adapter. Any idea?

OrderServiceTest:39 is line: `verify(eventPublisher).publishEvent(any(OrderPlacedEvent.class));`

Comment: Try making your test also Transactional.

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't work but is better. I updated my question and described what is the problem now. Could you look at it?

Comment: Remove the `@Transactional` from the test. That causes a rollback instead of a commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@EnableTransactionManagement`.

**EDIT**

This works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So47793485Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So47793485Application.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public static class Foo {

        @Transactional
        public void foo() {
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void afterCommit() {
                    System.out.println("here");
                }

                @Override
                public void afterCompletion(int status) {
                    System.out.println(
                            status == TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_COMMITTED ? "committed" : "rolled back");
                }

            });
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class So47793485ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    Foo foo;

    @Test
//  @Transactional
    public void contextLoads() {
        foo.foo();
    }

}
```

When I uncomment the `@Transactional` on the test, the tx rolls back.

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't work but is better. I updated my question and described what is the problem now. Could you look at it?

Comment: Remove the `@Transactional` from the test. That causes a rollback instead of a commit.

Comment: Without `@Transactional` I got an exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction synchronization is not active
` therefore I tried to add `@Transactionl` and `@Rollback(value = false)` but I got an exception from Mockito which I described above.

Comment: You need it on the method under test; you don't need it on the test. Which transaction manager are you using? My test works fine with a `DataSourceTransactionManager` - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It works, but now my question is how to mock EventPublisher because I get an error: `Wanted but not invoked:
applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(
    <any>
);
-> at com.transactions.demo.transactionsdemo.dao.OrderServiceTest.save(OrderServiceTest.java:53)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
`

Comment: Your `OrderService` instance needs to be managed by Spring in order for transactions to work, you can't just use `new OrderService(...)`.

Comment: I updated my again, because I still get an exception.

Comment: This could be a bug in Spring - I see it is injecting the real event publisher (the application context) instead of the mock. Adding a setter and calling `orderService.setEventPublisher(this.eventPublisher)` before calling `save()` will work.

Comment: Or, you could add an `ApplicationListener<OrderPlacedEvent>` to your test context and assert you received the event.

Comment: Thanks Gary! Both solutions are correct. I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 13):

I had to add

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.initSynchronization();
```

to my

```
@Before
public void init() {
```

method in order to initialize transaction synchronization before each test

also, don't forget to clear after each

```
@After
public void clear() {
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.clear();
```

Comment: Had a similar scenario:

Integration test with a service that registers an `afterCommit` hook. Repositories were mocked, thus I had to exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. This proposal made it work for me. The marked solution didn't work for me.